# Oracle MAF : How to render ResultSet list into AMX page?

Tags: java, oracle-maf

**Logic:** Display drop down (data from `TABLE_ONE`) in `page1.amx` and based on the selection it needs to get data from `TABLE_TWO`, then render the retrieved data into `page2.amx`. Below is the sample which I have tried,

---

I have created service class `ServiceClass.java` in my service package and created `DataControl (ServiceClassDC)` for that class.

From my `FirstPage.amx` I'm calling service class method using `valueChangeListener` in drop down (Drop down value will be populated from DB, let's take `TABLE_ONE` ID). Below is the piece of code for this logic,

**FirstPage.amx**

```
<amx:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.selectId.inputValue}" label="Select Id" id="soc1"
                         valueChangeListener="#{ServiceClass.callThisMethod}">
      <amx:selectItems value="#{bindings.selectId.items}" id="si1"/> 
</amx:selectOneChoice>
```

Based on the selection using **WHERE** condition, I got the list of objects in `productList` which is having the result set data.

**ServiceClass.java**

```
public void callThisMethod(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    System.out.println("Selected Value: "+valueChangeEvent.getNewValue());
    String selectedValue = valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().toString();

    ClassMappingDescriptor descriptor = ClassMappingDescriptor.getInstance(TableTwo.class);
    DBPersistenceManager pm = getLocalPersistenceManager();

    try{        
    StringBuffer sql = pm.getSqlSelectFromPart(descriptor);
    sql.append(" WHERE ID='"+selectedValue+"'");
    sql = pm.constructOrderByClause(sql, descriptor);
    ResultSet set = pm.executeSqlSelect(sql.toString(), new ArrayList());
    System.out.println("Result set >> "+set);
    List productList = pm.createEntitiesFromResultSet(set, (List) descriptor.getAttributeMappingsDirect());
    System.out.println("productList "+productList);
    } catch(Exception exp){
        System.out.println("Exception : "+exp);
    }

}
```

Now, I want to display the List object data `(productList)` into `SecondPage.amx` screen. How to do this?

Please comment below, if you want any more details regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose your `List productList` in a public method (so provide a get method) and expose that method in a Data Control. You can then drag and drop it on your page.

Example:

```
 public Product[] getProductArray() {  
     return (Product[]) productList.toArray();
 }
```

Note that this is an example from a MAF version where Java 1.4 was used!